# protobuf-net Specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0, protobuf-net

I have recently decided to use [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) to serialize large plain text data files my application uses to see if there is any performance gain over parsing the plain text data.

Data Class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ClimateFile : BaseModel
{
    #region Properties
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double Latitude { get { return GetValue(() => Latitude); } private set { SetValue(() => Latitude, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public double Longitude { get { return GetValue(() => Longitude); } private set { SetValue(() => Longitude, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Notes { get { return GetValue(() => Notes); } set { SetValue(() => Notes, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public DateTime MinDate { get { return GetValue(() => MinDate); } private set { SetValue(() => MinDate, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public DateTime MaxDate { get { return GetValue(() => MaxDate); } private set { SetValue(() => MaxDate, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public List<ClimateDailyData> DailyData { get { return GetValue(() => DailyData); } private set { SetValue(() => DailyData, value); } }
    #endregion

    #region Method
    public static ClimateFile Load(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper();
            if (ext == ".P51")
                return new ClimateFile(filePath);
            else if (ext == ".P51X")
            {
                ClimateFile climateFile;
                using (var file = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                {
                    climateFile = Serializer.Deserialize<ClimateFile>(file);
                }
                return climateFile;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(String.Format("The file \"{0}\" could not be opened, {1}", filePath, ExceptionUtilities.JoinExceptionMessages(e)));
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("filePath was not a .P51 or .P51X file.");
    }

    public void LoadP51File(string filePath)
    {
        List<string[]> lines = GetFileLines(filePath);
        Latitude = double.Parse(lines[0][0]);
        Longitude = double.Parse(lines[0][1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < lines[0].Length; ++i)
            Notes += String.Format("{0} ", lines[0][i]);
        MinDate = GetDate(lines[2][0]);
        MaxDate = GetDate(lines[lines.Count - 1][0]);

        // Parse daily data
        lines.RemoveRange(0, 2);
        var dailyData = lines.Select(row => new ClimateDailyData()
            {
                DataDate = GetDate(row[0]),
                MaxTemperature = double.Parse(row[2]),
                MinTemperature = double.Parse(row[3]),
                Rainfall = double.Parse(row[4]),
                Evaporation = double.Parse(row[5]),
                SolarRadiation = double.Parse(row[6])
            }).ToList();
        DailyData = dailyData;
    }

    public void SaveP51XFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var file = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<ClimateFile>(file, this);
        }
    }

    public List<string[]> GetFileLines(string filePath)
    {
        var rows = new List<string[]>();
        var cells = new List<string>();
        var cell = new StringBuilder();
        using (var fs = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
        {
            int buffer;
            while ((buffer = fs.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                char nextChar = (char)buffer;

                if (nextChar >= '!') // If the character is a non-whitespace printable character
                {
                    cell.Append(nextChar);
                    continue;
                }

                if (nextChar == ' ' || nextChar == '\t')
                {
                    if (cell.Length > 0)
                    {
                        cells.Add(cell.ToString());
                        cell.Clear();
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (nextChar == '\r' || nextChar == '\n')
                {
                    if (cell.Length > 0)
                    {
                        cells.Add(cell.ToString());
                        cell.Clear();
                    }
                    if (cells.Count > 0)
                    {
                        rows.Add(cells.ToArray());
                        cells.Clear();
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                throw new InvalidDataException("The climate file contains unknown characters.");
            }

            if (cell.Length > 0)
                cells.Add(cell.ToString());
            if (cells.Count > 0)
                rows.Add(cells.ToArray());
        }
        return rows;
    }

    public DateTime GetDate(string date)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        if (Disposed)
            return;
        if (DailyData != null)
            foreach (ClimateDailyData dailyData in DailyData)
                dailyData.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Initialization
    public ClimateFile()
    {
    }

    public ClimateFile(string filePath)
    {
        LoadP51File(filePath);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Collection Data Class:

```
    [ProtoContract]
public class ClimateDailyData : BaseModel
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime DataDate { get { return GetValue(() => DataDate); } set { SetValue(() => DataDate, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int JulianDay { get { return DataDate.DayOfYear; } }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public double MaxTemperature { get { return GetValue(() => MaxTemperature); } set { SetValue(() => MaxTemperature, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public double MinTemperature { get { return GetValue(() => MinTemperature); } set { SetValue(() => MinTemperature, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public double Rainfall { get { return GetValue(() => Rainfall); } set { SetValue(() => Rainfall, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public double Evaporation { get { return GetValue(() => Evaporation); } set { SetValue(() => Evaporation, value); } }

    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public double SolarRadiation { get { return GetValue(() => SolarRadiation); } set { SetValue(() => SolarRadiation, value); } }
}
```

Serialization Command:

```
public ICommand ImportP51
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(delegate
                {
                    OpenFileDialog openDialogue = new OpenFileDialog()
                    {
                        AddExtension = true,
                        CheckPathExists = true,
                        CheckFileExists = true,
                        DefaultExt = ".p51",
                        Filter = "Climate Files|*.p51",
                        InitialDirectory = DataPath,
                        Multiselect = false,
                        Title = "Select a File to Open"
                    };

                    if ((bool)openDialogue.ShowDialog())
                    {
                        string filePath = String.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            filePath = openDialogue.FileName;
                            var climate = new Climate();
                            climate.FilePath = filePath;
                            var savePath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.p51x", ClimateDataPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath));
                            climate.FileData.SaveP51XFile(savePath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The file \"{0}\" could not be opened, {1}", filePath, ExceptionUtilities.JoinExceptionMessages(e)), "Invalid File");
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

When executing `ImportP51`, I get the exception "Specified method is not supported", I am using protobuf-net V2 r594 which was released on the 12/10/2012 and am thinking of trying to use one of the previous versions if I cannot get it to work with this version. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to reconstruct a working version of the code (since I don't have your `BaseModel`) which I've done by using automatically implemented properties and adding an initializer for the list (`DailyData`), and explicitly referencing r594 from google-code. The only error I get is:

> Cannot apply changes to property ClimateDailyData.JulianDay

which makes sense, because it can't rightly deserialize data into a read-only property, so I removed the serialization marker from that one:

```
// [ProtoMember(2)] removed - serialized implicitly via DataData
public int JulianDay { get { return DataDate.DayOfYear; } }
```

After that it *worked fine*. Since I don't have your command framework, I have:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var climateFile = new ClimateFile();
        climateFile.InitSomeDataForSerialization();

        climateFile.SaveP51XFile("foo.P51X");
        var clone = ClimateFile.Load("foo.P51X");
    }
}
```

where `InitSomeDataForSerialization` just sets some of the values (since they have private setters, I can't do that in `Main`):

```
public void InitSomeDataForSerialization()
{
    Longitude = 10; Latitude = 4; Notes = "Test";

    DailyData.Add(
        new ClimateDailyData { DataDate = DateTime.Today, MinTemperature = 12, MaxTemperature = 35}
    );
}
```

And... it works.

On a hunch, I checked what happens if you reference "CoreOnly" instead of "Full", but that then refuses to compile because `Serializer.Serialize<T>` and `Serializer.Deserialize<T>` don't exist.

I'm happy to help, but as far as I can tell, nothing is wrong.

Things I would suggest next:

- show the full stack-trace of what happens in this exception, including any inner-exceptions (see the fix below)
- please check **exactly** which file you referenced in the 594 zip (look at "What Files Do I Need.txt", but I'd guess the correct one for you is "Full/net30/..."; the nuget package configures the most appropriate files automatically)
- please show a fully reproducible example, i.e. where I can press <kbd>F5</kbd> and see the exact exception (I had to change the code in the example for it to compile, which means I am no longer testing the same thing)

Fix for correct exception wrapping:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new InvalidDataException(String.Format("The file \"{0}\" could not be opened", filePath), e);
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I did not realize I still had the ProtoMember on the JulianDay in that example, I actually fixed that should have checked what I was pasting. But I got it working by reverting two versions to your December 2011 release. I added an issue to your project page, it even worked if I compiled the latest version, just not if I used the precompiled V2 r594 version from the downloads section. I would really like to use one of your recent featured releases if I could.

Comment: @Alex in my sample project here, I am explicitly using the downloaded r594. I can't make it fail. Can you still make it fail? If so, can you tell me exactly which dll you are referencing? (if that is tricky, the file size in bytes should be sufficient, I guess)

Comment: Well this is odd... I downloaded it again from your downloads section and this time it worked. I think I must have referenced the wrong dll or something which is quite embarrassing...

Comment: @Alex not a problem; let me know if you get any other issues - I'm happy to help.